# iOS array not being filled completely

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am using these two recursive methods to find the paths of files and directories in a certain folder

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getFilePathsFromDirectory:(NSString *)directory{
NSMutableArray *contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *arr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:nil];
for (NSString *file in arr) {
    BOOL isDir;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] isDirectory:&isDir];
    if (!isDir) {
        [contents addObject:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
    }
    else{
        [contents addObject:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]];
        [contents addObject:[self getFilePathsFromDirectory:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file]]];
    }
}
return contents;
}

- (NSString *)getPathForItemNamed:(NSString *)name array:(NSMutableArray *)arr{
NSString *str;
if (name) {
    for (NSString *s in arr) {
        if ([s isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            if ([[s lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:name]) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    for (NSMutableArray *aq in arr) {
        if ([aq isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            str = [self getPathForItemNamed:name array:aq];
            return str;
        }
    }
}
return str;
}
```

but the problem is, after going through a certain amount of subdirectories (3-5), this stops returning any path and returns `(null)`. I feel like this has to do with the array not being filled with all the directories before it returns for some reason. Heres how I call these

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [self getContentsOfPaths:[self downloadsDir]];

path = [self getPathForItemNamed:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text array:paths];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using getPathForNamed:array: here at all. Plus it seems when you are doing the recursion you add the returned array to the current array. Did you mean to add the contents of the returned array instead?

Comment: I had my old code up, thats why it looked like `getPathForItemNamed:array:` wasn't being called, a typo on my part. The reason I add the array is so it adds an array for each subdirectory in the original directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your `getPathForItemNamed:` method:

- When it cannot find a file by name, it returns a value of an uninitialized variable `str`. This is undefined behavior - you need to set `str` to `nil` upon initialization. In fact, you do not need `str` at all (see the fix below).
- When it discovers its first subdirectory, it assumes that the file that it is looking for must be inside that subdirectory, even if it is not. Whatever the first-level recursive invocation of `getPathForItemNamed:` returns, becomes the return result of the top-level invocation. This is bad: if the file that you are looking for is in the subtree of the second subdirectory, you are never going to find it!

Here is how you can fix your method:

```
- (NSString *)getPathForItemNamed:(NSString *)name array:(NSMutableArray *)arr{
    if (!name) return nil;
    for (NSString *s in arr) {
        if ([s isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            if ([[s lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:name]) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    for (NSMutableArray *aq in arr) {
        if ([aq isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            str = [self getPathForItemNamed:name array:aq];
            // Return something only when you find something
            if (str) return str;
        }
    }
    return nil; // You do not need str at all.
}
```